# how to override default Django form validation error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I try this but it doesn't work. default error message is shown only.please help............

```
from django import forms
from SharedApps_Application.models import certificateDb
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget
from django.forms.fields import DateField

my_default_errors = {
    'required': 'Application field is required',
}

class CertificateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    startdate = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1995, 2100)))
    expiredate = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1995, 2100)))
    application = forms.CharField(error_messages = my_default_errors)
    class Meta:
        model = certificateDb
        fields = ('application', 'startdate', 'expiredate', 'environment_type','File' )
```

> screenshot

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zhM6.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rXId.png)

> update

```
from django import forms
from SharedApps_Application.models import certificateDb
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget
from django.forms.fields import DateField
class CertificateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    startdate = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1995, 2100)))
    expiredate = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1995, 2100)))
    application = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = certificateDb
        fields = ('application', 'startdate', 'expiredate', 'environment_type','File' )

        error_messages = {
            'application': {
                'required': ("Application field is required"),
            },
            }
```

Comment: Which field error message do you want to override?

Comment: application field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the screenshot you just added, you want to change the error messages the browser renders to the client. This can be done by adding an `oninvalid` attribute to your field.

Here is how it's done in your forms.py file:

```
from django import forms
from SharedApps_Application.models import certificateDb
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget
from django.forms.fields import DateField


class CertificateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    app_attributes = {'oninvalid': 'this.setCustomValidity("Application field is required")', 'oninput': 'this.setCustomValidity("")'}
    startdate = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1995, 2100)))
    expiredate = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1995, 2100)))
    application = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=app_attributes)
    class Meta:
        model = certificateDb
        fields = ('application', 'startdate', 'expiredate', 'environment_type','File' )

        error_messages = {
            'application': {
                'required': ("Application field is required"),
            },
            }
```

---

Assuming the field you want to override is `'application'`. Add a `error_messages` dictionary under your class Meta like this:

**OLD ANSWER** - Overriding Django forms validation error messages

```
from django import forms
from SharedApps_Application.models import certificateDb
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget
from django.forms.fields import DateField


class CertificateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    startdate = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1995, 2100)))
    expiredate = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1995, 2100)))
    application = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = certificateDb
        fields = ('application', 'startdate', 'expiredate', 'environment_type','File' )

        error_messages = {
            'application': {
                'required': ("Application field is required"),
            },
            }
```

Comment: Yeah you need to remove my_default_errors from the application field. I edited the code again, try now.

Comment: not working. also pasted the screenshot above please look

Comment: I updated my answer. Should work now for both client and server validation messages.

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you! If you find this answer helpful you can accept it by clicking the check mark sign under the voting arrows. [Accepting An Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)